# How can I sort by "release" in Mysql, where e.g. 10.10 comes after 10.9, with non-numerical entries both before and after?

Tags: mysql, order-by, sorting, cast

If I have a table as per https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/arPEdUty3U6AJEQfqYEyRc/1 with a list of releases:

```
INSERT INTO `releases` (`ReleaseID`, `ReleaseNumber`) VALUES
(1, '10.6'),
(2, '10.8'),
(3, '_TBD'),
(4, '10.9'),
(5, 'Future'),
(6, '10.10'),
(7, '10.11');
```

How can I sort it so that things starting with `_` come first, then numbers, ordered as `10.6`, `10.8`, `10.9`, `10.10`, `10.11`, then anything else?

My current casting attempt (`CAST(ReleaseNumber as SIGNED INTEGER)` puts `Future` after `_TBD` instead of at the end.

The desired output of this example would be

`_TBD`, `10.6`, `10.8`, `10.9`, `10.10`, `10.11`, `Future`

Comment: Not easy in SQL; PHP has "natural" ordering.

Comment: I would add another integer column to the `releases` table you show, call it `sort_order` or something like that (because `order` is a reserved keyword). Then you can `ORDER BY releases.sort_order`. You can update the values to change the order anytime you want.

Comment: Easy in MariaDB (10.7+) with [NATURAL_SORT_KEY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/natural_sort_key/) like [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nvWkgdV8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM releases
ORDER BY LEFT(ReleaseNumber, 1) <> '_',                -- start with '_' - put first
         ReleaseNumber + 0 = 0,                        -- non-numeric - put last
         0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(ReleaseNumber, '.', 1),   -- sort by int part
         0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(ReleaseNumber, '.', -1);  -- sort by frac as int part
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!